# Get location from Facebook Account API

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I've made lots of attempts to get the city for this account to view the account on the app but it dont work

```
//Login Facebook
    public void Login()
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Home.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_login);
        login_button = (LoginButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login_button.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends","user_location");
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        dialog.show();
        login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                GraphRequest graphRequest = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(final JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        try {
                            SaveSystem.SaveStringData("userid" , object.getString("id"));
                            SaveSystem.SaveStringData("first_name" , object.getString("first_name"));
                            SaveSystem.SaveStringData("last_name" , object.getString("last_name"));
                            SaveSystem.SaveStringData("gender" , object.getString("gender"));
                            SaveSystem.SaveStringData("admin" , "0");
                            SaveSystem.SaveStringData("ban" , "0");
                            SaveSystem.SaveStringData("type" , "facebook");

                            //CheckUser
                            final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Home.this);
                            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Information.URL_CheckUsers + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("userid"), new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    try {
                                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Location " + object.getJSONObject("location").getJSONObject("location").getString("city"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    if(response.equals("0"))
                                    {
                                        //Add Account
                                        String URL_AddUser = Information.URL_AddUsers + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("userid") + "&username=" + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("first_name") + " " + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("last_name") + "&gender=" + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("gender") + "&admin=" + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("admin") + "&ban=" + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("ban") + "&type=" + SaveSystem.LoadStringData("type");
                                        StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_AddUser , new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                                setAccountData();

                                            }
                                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                        requestQueue.add(stringRequest1);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        setAccountData();
                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                }
                            });
                            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, last_name, email,gender, birthday, location{location}");
                graphRequest.setParameters(parameters);
                graphRequest.executeAsync();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

here I try to present the area to experience

```
try {
                                        Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Location " + object.getJSONObject("location").getJSONObject("location").getString("city"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

can I view Json facebook on Chrome ?? , I do not know how to arrange Json on facebook

I searched a lot but I dont get the city. Is it a problem in my blades or what please help me really thank you

Comment: If you’re unclear about the exact structure of the JSON you are getting back, then use Graph API Explorer to get an idea ... https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Clocation%7Blocation%7D&version=v2.11

Comment: but he rutern null location

Comment: Then you did not request the necessary permission. (Pay attention to what app id you are using GAE with.)

Comment: how do I ask for permission? you can help me :(

Comment: If you granted the permission in your app already, then you don’t need to do anything else any more besides choosing your app from the dropdown menu. Via "Get Token" you can grant additional permissions.